# SpotBugsTask: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.Object org.gradle.util.DeprecationLogger

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, spotbugs

with Gradle 6.7 and spotbugs toolVersion 4.1.4. I am getting following error.

looks like I have to exclude some unwanted version, any help?

stack trace

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskInstantiationException: Could not create task of type 'SpotBugsTask'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.TaskFactory$1.call(TaskFactory.java:97)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.TaskFactory$1.call(TaskFactory.java:84)
        at org.gradle.util.GUtil.uncheckedCall(GUtil.java:442)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.injectIntoNewInstance(AbstractTask.java:201)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.TaskFactory.create(TaskFactory.java:84)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.create(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:48)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.createTask(DefaultTaskContainer.java:326)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.access$200(DefaultTaskContainer.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreatingProvider.createDomainObject(DefaultTaskContainer.java:701)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreatingProvider.createDomainObject(DefaultTaskContainer.java:658)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection$AbstractDomainObjectCreatingProvider.tryCreate(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:941)
        ... 180 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.Object org.gradle.util.DeprecationLogger.whileDisabled(org.gradle.internal.Factory)'
        at com.github.spotbugs.SpotBugsTask.createReports(SpotBugsTask.java:102)
        at com.github.spotbugs.SpotBugsTask.<init>(SpotBugsTask.java:98)
        at com.github.spotbugs.SpotBugsTask_Decorated.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.AsmBackedClassGenerator$InvokeConstructorStrategy.newInstance(AsmBackedClassGenerator.java:1969)
        at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.AbstractClassGenerator$GeneratedClassImpl$GeneratedConstructorImpl.newInstance(AbstractClassGenerator.java:468)
        at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.DependencyInjectingInstantiator.doCreate(DependencyInjectingInstantiator.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.DependencyInjectingInstantiator.newInstanceWithDisplayName(DependencyInjectingInstantiator.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.TaskFactory$1.call(TaskFactory.java:90)
        ... 190 more
```

my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        ..
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.github.spotbugs.snom:spotbugs-gradle-plugin:4.6.0'
        ..
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.github.spotbugs'


spotbugs {
    toolVersion = "4.1.4"
}

tasks.withType(SpotBugsTask) {
    xml.enabled = true
    html.enabled = false
}
```

gradel.wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

gradle --version

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.7
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-10-14 16:13:12 UTC
Revision:     312ba9e0f4f8a02d01854d1ed743b79ed996dfd3

Kotlin:       1.3.72
Groovy:       2.5.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.8 compiled on May 10 2020
JVM:          15.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 15.0.1+9)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.15.7 x86_64
```

Comment: java version, build.gradle, sample project?

Comment: you are btw not using gradle `6.7` that is why a minimal reproducible example is needed. I would have voted to close this question, but your bounty is not allowing me to do that. Unless you provide details - you are going to get answers like below, that _entirely_ miss your set-up and question.

Comment: updated more details

Comment: can you provide a repo where you can reproduce this? And btw `tasks.withType(SpotBugsTask) {` this should _not_ work at all.  look [here](https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs-gradle-plugin/issues/32). And I will repeat that it surely looks like you are not using `gradle 6.7` because `org.gradle.util.DeprecationLogger` is named differently there

Answer (score 2):

well, i think you should show your `build.gradle`, otherwise no one can help you.

my `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id "com.github.spotbugs" version "4.6.0"
}


// To generate an HTML report instead of XML
spotbugsMain {
    reports {
        xml.enabled = false
        html.enabled = true
    }
}
```

for:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.6
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-08-10 22:06:19 UTC
Revision:     d119144684a0c301aea027b79857815659e431b9

Kotlin:       1.3.72
Groovy:       2.5.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.8 compiled on May 10 2020
JVM:          14.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 14.0.1+7)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.15.7 x86_64
```